# Date when the custom field was added

Tags: php, customization

I have a couple of custom fields setup and working fine, is there any way to show the date when the custom field was created within the post template? I tried searching around, but no luck.

For example:

```
name: test1 - value: result1     -------- created 10/02/09
name: test2 - value: result2     -------- created 15/03/10
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By default, there are no creation dates associated with custom meta fields. If you [check the description](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_postmeta), you can see that it is a very simple table of key/value pairs associated with a post ID, plus an auto-increment field. There is no time component at all.

The only thing you can do with default functionality is get relative dates by checking the `meta_id` field. That is an auto-increment field which is incremented by one every time a new row is created. Lower numbers are always older than higher numbers, but there is not way to get a calendar date. If you need that functionality, you will need to create it yourself. I don't think I understand what you want well enough to attempt code.

Answer (score -2):

For a rough estimate, you could check the database for first entries to the field.